# Problems with list's of objects cast

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make simple tcp server work with multiple clients. For this I need to use select or poll methods.
I've written TcpFileTransfer class:

```
 class TcpFileTransfer:

    def __init__(self, conn, adrr):
            self.fullsize = 0
            self.sent = 0
            self.interrupted = False
            self.conn = conn
            self.address = adrr

    def dispose(self):
            self.interrupted = False
            self.sent = 0
            self.fullsize = 0

    def getconn(self):
           return self.conn
    def send_urgent(self):
            percentage = self.sent/self.fullsize
            if percentage < 1:
                    percentage *= 100
            else:
                    percentage = 100
            percentage = math.trunc(percentage)
            urgent = struct.pack('B', percentage)
            self.conn.send(urgent, socket.MSG_OOB)
            print(str(percentage) + "%")

    def download(self, data):
            if data.endswith("continue"):
                    data = data[0: -8]
                    self.interrupted = True
            filename = data[8:].strip()

            if os.path.exists(filename):
                    print("Start to download " + filename + "from server")
                    self.fullsize = os.path.getsize(filename)
            else:
                    print("File doesn't exist")
                    return

            with open(filename,'rb') as f:
                    self.conn.settimeout(2.0)
                    if self.interrupted:
                            f.read(self.sent)
                            self.sent += 1024
                    else:
                            self.sent = 1024
                    try:
                            bytes_to_send = f.read(1024)
                            i = 0
                            while bytes_to_send:
                                    self.conn.send(bytes_to_send)
                                    bytes_to_send = f.read(1024)
                                    self.sent += 1024
                                    i += 1
                                    if i % 20 == 0:
                                            self.send_urgent()
                    except socket.timeout:
                            print("Timeout Error")
                            self.interrupted = True
                            self.conn.close()
                            return
            print("Downloaded " + filename)
            self.dispose()

    def data_recieving(self):
            conn.setblocking(1)
            try:
                    udata = self.conn.recv(1024)
                    data = udata.decode("utf-8")
                    return data
            except BlockingIOError:
                    return None

    def tcp_loop(self):
            print("In loop")
            while True:
                    data = self.data_recieving()
                    if data:
                            print(data)
                            if data == "Quit":
                                    self.conn.close()
                                    s.close()
                                    sys.exit(0)
                            elif data == "Time":
                                    curtime = time.localtime()
                                    curtime = str(curtime)
                                    utime = curtime.encode("utf-8")
                                    self.conn.send(utime)
                            elif data.startswith("echo"):
                                    data = data[4:]
                                    print(data)
                                    self.conn.send(data.strip().encode("utf-8"))
                            elif data.startswith("download"):
                                    self.connection(self.conn)
                                    self.download(data)
                            else:
                                    print("Unrecognised command")
```

I've tried to call it here:

```
 tcp_clients = []
 client_addr = []
 if isCorrect:
    s.listen(5)
    while True:
            conn, addr = nonbloking_connection(s)
            if(conn):
                    if addr not in client_addr:
                            x = TcpFileTransfer(conn, addr)
                            print(type(x))
                            tcp_clients.append(x)
                            print("Added")

            for client in tcp_clients:
                    print(type(client))
                    client.tcp_loop()
```

The problem is in cast. The type of x variable is

```
 <class '__main__.TcpFileTransfer'>
```

And the type of client is

```
 <class 'socket.socket'>
```

Why do this cast occurred at all and what should I use to save collection of objects?

Comment: Well, it looks like you have a socket in your `tcp_clients`. You need to show us ALL the code where stuff gets added to the list.

Comment: This needs a [mcve]. As it is, there's no way for us to answer it.